# What field needs to be changed to update this specific header?

Tags: file, resources, docusignapi, signing, missing-features

In my mobile app, we use the docusign API to create a pdf enveloppe in a mobile app and change its content to match our customers expectations.
There are text components of the pdf that I'm supposed to be able to change, like DocuSign_SignerPlacedCompleteConfirm. Problem is, when changing the value, nothing appears on the enveloppe, while the change does happen for other fields.

Our doc includes the Docusign-Signing-Resource-File pdf v2.0 and the original resource file from docusign (master downloaded on their site).
I've already observed a difference between our master resource file and what the doc says about what's inside.
So I guessed that the field key was not the right one and I tried other names for the key, like placing "_Mobile" at the end.
But it still doesn't work.

I really feel like the doc is missing something, and it bothers me as everything looks changeable and this item is supposed to be but I can't get it to change.

`<data name="DocuSign_SignerPlacedCompleteConfirm">Bla bla bla</data>`

doesn't change the field I want. But

`<data name="DocuSign_HelpfulStart_Mobile">Click on START to start</data>`

does change something, a text which is near the previous one.

The field I want to change is circled in black here :
[Field to change](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rSRAS.jpg)

App is coded in React Native, opens a WebView in which you can see above page, generated by DocuSign.

I can't see any error log from docusign, and I just expect my text in the header to be set at 'Bla bla bla' for example. Instead, it's set at the default value.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Unfortunately I don't quite understand your problem statement. Please update (edit) your question to provide more details like:
Is the mobile app native or is the DocuSign web Signing Ceremony being used from a mobile?  Have you been able to successfully make any branding changes at all? Not every item in the signing ceremony is controlled by the branding file....

Comment: Can you post a screenshot that shows exactly what you're trying to change?

Comment: Hi, sorry I added a few elements to make it more complete.
And I've been successful in making other changes in the ceremony. For example, this title header at the previous step of signing

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry Axel, but I'm afraid what you are asking is not possible.

Changing the UI of the actual signature tabs in a signed envelope is not supported at this time.

It is a major security concern to enable this type of change, as it would potentially allow someone to make it look like someone else signed their envelope.